# Azure handling different IPs when scaling

Tags: linux, networking, azure, ip

I want to spin up redundant instances depending on the current load. So when there's much load, spawn more instances, if there's low traffic, shut down unnecessary instances.

I therefore want to use the VM ScaleSet with each instance using the same image.
I also use **autoscaling** for the ScaleSet

When spawning new instances, they by default have different/ new IPs. But I need the instances to **all be**

- reachable via the same IP address
- appear to servers they talk to as the same IP address

So what i'm basically looking for is a proxy. I have thought about setting up a proxy inside the image, but I suspect a better, more 'Azure' way.

I know there are Gateways and Loadbalancers, but I am not really sure on how to assign them to the automatically spawned instances, while it would be more straight forward, if i manually set the pool of instances.

Can anyone point me to the right direction, as I am a bit overwhelmed of how much there is in Azure.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for actually used to be the default for scale sets, which is to put them behind a load balancer. The load balancer will get a single IP, which is static, and then distribute the traffic to the nodes in the scale set.

The [guide here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/quick-create-portal) shows you how to create a scale set with a load balanacer.